# beamer inserts blank slide against my will

Tags: beamer

Beamer is introducing a blank slide (the last one) for some reason unkown to me (in the larger document, it also inserts a blank page between the two frames in the code below). Please help.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[style=mla,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\graphicspath{ {charts/} }
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\subsubsection{Von den ersten Wahlen zu den zweiten Wahlen (1977-9)}
\frame[allowframebreaks]{
\frametitle{Konsens und Verfassung}
\begin{itemize}
\item Die 1977-79 Zeitspanne war von politischem Konsens vor allem zwischen PSOE, PCE und UCD geprägt, weil: die UCD hatte keine Mehrheit, das Militär war immer noch eine Bedrohung, Wirtschaftskrise, links- und rechtsextremer Terrorismus, die Forderung nach Dezentralisierung und natürliche die Erlassung einer neuen Verfassung, welche so viele politischen Kräfte wie möglich einbinden sollte (Legitimität). Das Ergebnis waren die Pactos de Moncloa 
\item Ursprünglich bzw. offiziell war es nicht geplant gewesen, eine neue Verfassung auszuarbeiten (Carmona, 2005:119-1). Sie wurde am 23. December 1978 verabschiedet. Es gab 13 Enthaltungen, davon drei von der AP und sieben von der PNV, und sechs Gegenstimmen, 5 davon von der AP (Carmona, 2005:125).
\item In der folgenden Volksabstimmung stimmten 67 Prozent der Bevölkerung ab, mit 88 Prozent dafür und 8 Prozen dagegen. Am 27. Dezember wurde die Verfassung im Parlament verabschiedet, am 29. Dezember 1978 trat sie in Kraft(de Estaban, 1989:296-8).
\end{itemize}}

\subsubsection{Von den zweiten Wahlen zum Kollaps der UCD (1979-1982)} 
\frame[allowframebreaks]{
\frametitle{Das Ende der Transition}
\begin{itemize}
\item Desencanto: Entzauberung der Bevölkerung, die sich von der Transition mehr erhofft hatte: Von den Moncloa Pacts wurde eigentlich nur anti-inflationäre Wirtschaftspolitik umgesetzt, die ``gleichen Leute'' waren immer noch an der Macht, die Verfassung wurde ohne den Input der Gesellschaft ausgearbeitet, Terrorismus, Arbeitslosigkeit, eine immer noch schlechte Wirtschaftslage (Caciagli, 1986:125-7)
\item Der politische Konsens wird erst einmal für beendet erklärt, die UCD wird von AP und PSOE hart angegangen, Suarez verliert zusehends die Kontrolle über die unterschiedlichen ideologischen Gruppierungen seiner Partei. Im Februar 1981 tritt er als Ministerpräsident zurück.
\item Calvo-Sotelo, der Nachfolger von Suarez, soll am 20. January vom Parlament gewählt werden. In der zweiten Abstimmungsrunde am 23. Februar 1981 versucht ein Teil des Militärs, die Macht zu ergreifen. 
\item Nach dem Coup wurde wieder eine Periode der engen politischen Kooperation eingeleitet.Unter  Calvo Sotelo wird das Ley de Defensa de la Democraica (Marzo 1981), das LOAPA und der Acuerdo Nactional sobre el Empleo verabschiedet, mit der Hilfe der PSOE (Powell, 2001:299, 302-4)
\item Im Oktober 1981 wird Spanien gegen den Willen der PSOE, welche darüber ein Referendum abhalten wollte, NATO Mitglied. Gonzales verspricht, dass sollte er die Wahlen gewinnen, er ein Referendum über den Verbleib Spaniens in der NATO abhalten würde (Powell, 2001:309). 
\end{itemize}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I would suggest you to rephrase something in the text so, that it will be reduced by one line... (For example remove the last parenthesis to see that everything is fine). A bug report to `beamer` (I suppose it is in `source2e` package), would be good (usefull) too.

Comment: You should use the environment version of `frame` (so `\begin{frame}...\end{frame}` instead of `\frame`). The macro version is only for backwards compatibility.

Comment: To be honest, this looks like a horrifying presentation, imho. You have way too much on each slide and you shouldn't put whole sentences on your slides. The slides should not replace what you say, they should assist what you say.

Comment: @Skillmon I humbly support your humble opinion...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. If I don't put all the info, the students are going to be complaining, however, that they cannot do anything with the slides.

Comment: Using `allowframebreaks` is evil. And as said previously, you don't need `graphicx` and `hyperref`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The empty frames are added because `beamer` checks the size of what you want to put in that slide and thinks that it'll need 3 slides to fit everything. You can reduce the (estimated) size by making some minor changes as koleygr suggested. Another option would be to remove the vertical white space added by `\end{itemize}` using an `\unskip`. `\unskip` undoes the last made skip if it's the last item on the list (a kern is not considered a skip -- in fact the TeXbook description is: removes a glue item or leaders). Therefore the following removes the empty slide.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[style=mla,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\graphicspath{ {charts/} }
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\subsubsection{Von den ersten Wahlen zu den zweiten Wahlen (1977-9)}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{Konsens und Verfassung}
\begin{itemize}
\item Die 1977-79 Zeitspanne war von politischem Konsens vor allem zwischen PSOE, PCE und UCD geprägt, weil: die UCD hatte keine Mehrheit, das Militär war immer noch eine Bedrohung, Wirtschaftskrise, links- und rechtsextremer Terrorismus, die Forderung nach Dezentralisierung und natürliche die Erlassung einer neuen Verfassung, welche so viele politischen Kräfte wie möglich einbinden sollte (Legitimität). Das Ergebnis waren die Pactos de Moncloa 
\item Ursprünglich bzw. offiziell war es nicht geplant gewesen, eine neue Verfassung auszuarbeiten (Carmona, 2005:119-1). Sie wurde am 23. December 1978 verabschiedet. Es gab 13 Enthaltungen, davon drei von der AP und sieben von der PNV, und sechs Gegenstimmen, 5 davon von der AP (Carmona, 2005:125).
\item In der folgenden Volksabstimmung stimmten 67 Prozent der Bevölkerung ab, mit 88 Prozent dafür und 8 Prozen dagegen. Am 27. Dezember wurde die Verfassung im Parlament verabschiedet, am 29. Dezember 1978 trat sie in Kraft(de Estaban, 1989:296-8).
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\subsubsection{Von den zweiten Wahlen zum Kollaps der UCD (1979-1982)} 
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{Das Ende der Transition}
\begin{itemize}
\item Desencanto: Entzauberung der Bevölkerung, die sich von der Transition mehr erhofft hatte: Von den Moncloa Pacts wurde eigentlich nur anti-inflationäre Wirtschaftspolitik umgesetzt, die ``gleichen Leute'' waren immer noch an der Macht, die Verfassung wurde ohne den Input der Gesellschaft ausgearbeitet, Terrorismus, Arbeitslosigkeit, eine immer noch schlechte Wirtschaftslage (Caciagli, 1986:125-7)
\item Der politische Konsens wird erst einmal für beendet erklärt, die UCD wird von AP und PSOE hart angegangen, Suarez verliert zusehends die Kontrolle über die unterschiedlichen ideologischen Gruppierungen seiner Partei. Im Februar 1981 tritt er als Ministerpräsident zurück.
\item Calvo-Sotelo, der Nachfolger von Suarez, soll am 20. January vom Parlament gewählt werden. In der zweiten Abstimmungsrunde am 23. Februar 1981 versucht ein Teil des Militärs, die Macht zu ergreifen. 
\item Nach dem Coup wurde wieder eine Periode der engen politischen Kooperation eingeleitet.Unter  Calvo Sotelo wird das Ley de Defensa de la Democraica (Marzo 1981), das LOAPA und der Acuerdo Nactional sobre el Empleo verabschiedet, mit der Hilfe der PSOE (Powell, 2001:299, 302-4)
\item Im Oktober 1981 wird Spanien gegen den Willen der PSOE, welche darüber ein Referendum abhalten wollte, NATO Mitglied. Gonzales verspricht, dass sollte er die Wahlen gewinnen, er ein Referendum über den Verbleib Spaniens in der NATO abhalten würde (Powell, 2001:309). 
\end{itemize}\unskip
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I thought I fixed the misinformation about how much `\unskip` strips (is it clear enough as it is currently?).

Comment: yes the new text is fine, I deleted the original comment

Answer (score 0):

Without change in your content:

(placed last parentheses "inside" `\small` font)

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage{verbatim}
%\usepackage[style=mla,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\graphicspath{ {charts/} }
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\subsubsection{Von den ersten Wahlen zu den zweiten Wahlen (1977-9)}
\frame[allowframebreaks]{
\frametitle{Konsens und Verfassung}
\begin{itemize}
\item Die 1977-79 Zeitspanne war von politischem Konsens vor allem zwischen PSOE, PCE und UCD geprägt, weil: die UCD hatte keine Mehrheit, das Militär war immer noch eine Bedrohung, Wirtschaftskrise, links- und rechtsextremer Terrorismus, die Forderung nach Dezentralisierung und natürliche die Erlassung einer neuen Verfassung, welche so viele politischen Kräfte wie möglich einbinden sollte (Legitimität). Das Ergebnis waren die Pactos de Moncloa 
\item Ursprünglich bzw. offiziell war es nicht geplant gewesen, eine neue Verfassung auszuarbeiten (Carmona, 2005:119-1). Sie wurde am 23. December 1978 verabschiedet. Es gab 13 Enthaltungen, davon drei von der AP und sieben von der PNV, und sechs Gegenstimmen, 5 davon von der AP (Carmona, 2005:125).
\item In der folgenden Volksabstimmung stimmten 67 Prozent der Bevölkerung ab, mit 88 Prozent dafür und 8 Prozen dagegen. Am 27. Dezember wurde die Verfassung im Parlament verabschiedet, am 29. Dezember 1978 trat sie in Kraft(de Estaban, 1989:296-8).
\end{itemize}}

\subsubsection{Von den zweiten Wahlen zum Kollaps der UCD (1979-1982)} 
\frame[allowframebreaks]{
\frametitle{Das Ende der Transition}
\begin{itemize}
\item Desencanto: Entzauberung der Bevölkerung, die sich von der Transition mehr erhofft hatte: Von den Moncloa Pacts wurde eigentlich nur anti-inflationäre Wirtschaftspolitik umgesetzt, die ``gleichen Leute'' waren immer noch an der Macht, die Verfassung wurde ohne den Input der Gesellschaft ausgearbeitet, Terrorismus, Arbeitslosigkeit, eine immer noch schlechte Wirtschaftslage {\small (Caciagli, 1986:125-7)}
\item Der politische Konsens wird erst einmal für beendet erklärt, die UCD wird von AP und PSOE hart angegangen, Suarez verliert zusehends die Kontrolle über die unterschiedlichen ideologischen Gruppierungen seiner Partei. Im Februar 1981 tritt er als Ministerpräsident zurück.
\item Calvo-Sotelo, der Nachfolger von Suarez, soll am 20. January vom Parlament gewählt werden. In der zweiten Abstimmungsrunde am 23. Februar 1981 versucht ein Teil des Militärs, die Macht zu ergreifen. 
\item Nach dem Coup wurde wieder eine Periode der engen politischen Kooperation eingeleitet.Unter  Calvo Sotelo wird das Ley de Defensa de la Democraica {\small (Marzo 1981)}, das LOAPA und der Acuerdo Nactional sobre el Empleo verabschiedet, mit der Hilfe der PSOE {\small (Powell, 2001:299, 302-4)}
\item Im Oktober 1981 wird Spanien gegen den Willen der PSOE, welche darüber ein Referendum abhalten wollte, NATO Mitglied. Gonzales verspricht, dass sollte er die Wahlen gewinnen, er ein Referendum über den Verbleib Spaniens in der NATO abhalten würde {\small(Powell, 2001:309)}. 
\end{itemize}
}

\end{document}
```

But if you don't like it just make a small rephrase in last frame. (reduce the last line)

PS: As suggested in my comment a bug report for an opensource project (and much more for latex) is always useful

Comment: You could use an `\unskip` after the `\end{itemize}` instead. That wouldn't have any visible difference and still work.

Comment: @Skillmon it is a different answer that I suppose you may write... I don't know about `\unskip` and will look about it soon. Thanks. (make it an answer, because I don't even know what `\unskip` "means")